# VisualStudio 2017 Community won't start

Tags: visual-studio, crash, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

IDE crashes on startup, at the splash screen. I have looked into logs and found a bunch of errors:

```
    <entry>
    <record>14</record>
    <time>2017/07/09 07:28:50.672</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp.</description>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>15</record>
    <time>2017/07/09 07:28:50.672</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp.</description>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>16</record>
    <time>2017/07/09 07:28:50.672</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefCache flags</description>
    <hr>00003801</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>17</record>
    <time>2017/07/09 07:28:50.672</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp.</description>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>18</record>
    <time>2017/07/09 07:28:50.672</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp.</description>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
  </entry>
```

I tried to reinstall VS, remove all extensions etc but nothing helped me

**UPD:** it doesn't work with /setup

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. Maybe it will help. I know it's for Visual Studio 2012 but might apply here as well

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/450f2b30-e902-4dad-870a-457b331f932f/could-not-find-configurationchanged-timestamp-error-message-appears-in-activitylogxml-while?forum=vsx

Comment: What version of windows are you using and are you running VS as admin or user? If not, try running VS with admin rights.